# How to host image at https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/{path}/{filename}?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I'm a developer, I need many screenshots to put in `readme.md` file where to store or host it? I found out that some people use [https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/{path}/{filename}](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/%7Bpath%7D/%7Bfilename%7D) to host their image and link them with `readme.md` file. How to put images there?

Answer (score 34):

You can create a `.github/images` directory in your repo and add all your assets there.
Assets added here will be available on

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{github_user_name}/{repo_name}/{branch}/.github/images/{asset_name}.{asset_extension}
```

Once you push `.github/images` directory to remote your assets should be available through the mentioned link.

And https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/ is used by GitHub to store images added in issues, PR's, etc.,

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

You can also create an assets directory in the root of your repo and use a relative path to the image.

```
/assets/{asset_name}.{asset_extension}

![Alt Text](/assets/{asset_name}.{asset_extension})
```

With this, images can be previewed without actually pushing to remote.

**Hosting on user-images.githubusercontent.com subdomain**

If you do not intend to store any images in your repository, you can always use this https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/

To host your images in user-images subdomain you can do the following

1. Click New Issue this will open up the issue creator.
2. Drag and Drop or Upload your image in the body content
3. Wait for upload completion and copy the URL for the image.
4. Cancel the issue creation and continue.

But you will not have access to these images once uploaded, you cannot delete them. You can always contact GitHub Support if required to delete.

Comment: You may want to fix the example URL to make it more general, currently it seems to contain your username and repository name.

Comment: But adding images in repository will create unwanted bulk to the project. Any other good alternative. And if I have to get this https://user-images.githubusercontent.com I have to post an issue and upload Image there am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Opening an issue isn't necessary.
1. Click New Issue.
2. Upload the image in issue body wait for upload completion and grab the URL.
3. Abort the process.

But, I should warn you that you will not have access to images (you cannot delete it once uploaded if you want, have to contact GitHub Support).

Comment: @PoojaBhatia I have updated the answer with more details! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you sir for helping, got my answer. But will GitHub delete those images as I'm just opening issue and cancelling it.

Comment: No once uploaded images will not be deleted, unless you request.

Comment: Github may at any time introduce a garbage collector that runs every so often to delete "issue" images that are not referenced in any github issue. Just because it works for you at the time of writing doesn't mean it is a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for ur thoughts, I am well aware of that and quite surprised that its nt implemented yet. Lot of space is wasted due to this. And If u had read the previous comments u might hav noticed that I updated answer only after question author wanted to know how to do the issue upload process. My main answer was to keep the images in repo as assets or something. Also, many answers get outdated as technology advances and new things come into place, so there is never a good solution in my perspective. We utilise whatever works best and improvise it over time.

Comment: Any reason why that directory is named `.github/images` and not just a normal directory outside of `.github`?

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working for me.

Comment: @JimmyR.T. No reason to have images, it can be named anything. Also, there is no limitation to keep this directory under the `.github` directory, Please check the `UPDATE` part of the answer. Thanks

Comment: @codesnerd The answer has 2 options. Could you please share with us which one is not working or possibly a dummy repo of the non-working version. So that it would be easy to check and help with it. Thanks.

Comment: @KRRISH96 I tried the `.github` directory method but somehow it didn't work for me. However, simply dragging and dropping the image into the `README` worked just fine.

Comment: Re:  user-images.githubusercontent.com

"But you will not have access to these images once uploaded, you cannot delete them. You can always contact GitHub Support if required to delete."

This is the weird part. I wish I could access this. It would be nice if GitHub had a "/images" solution build-in somehow.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about it, AFAIK user-images.githubusercontent.com is not intended for user controlled storage it's for GitHub. Its ideal to have a dedicated  images directory in repo itself.

Comment: `4. Cancel the issue creation and continue.`

Has been helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Just drag and drop your image from your local pc to github readme in editable mode.

Comment: worked well for me!

Answer (score 6):

I took a screenshot of a diagram and tried to paste it directly into a comment in GitHub and it was automatically uploaded to "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/" and embedded as a markdown tag. Then I tried to paste the same tag into a readme.MD with the same link and worked for me.
[image: Comment]

Comment: This was genius! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

When you are editing the readme file on github, you have to drag the file you want to add in this specific box. That worked for me. If I dropped it anywhere else, it wouldn't load.

[image: Github readme screenshot]

Comment: Also, I think they should be 1 MB or less

Answer (score 2):

While editing `readme.md` in GitHub UI, paste the image from the clipboard directly in the readme, and the image is automatically uploaded into `user-images.gitHubusercontent`, and the link is updated in the readme to show the image.

Answer (score 1):

To add or store them just open the issues click on new issue and drag and drop your desired image in comment section and wait for it to upload in user-images.gitHubusercontent. when its done just copy that and paste it to your README.md file

Answer (score -1):

You can simply put the file where you want it in yours repository, click on the file from the github.com page and left click the `Raw` button or right click `Download` button and select `Copy link address`. It will show the full path url, then you can just put it into any Markdown text.